# Create a dynamic table with predefined columns using model in CSHTML MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to create a dynamic table using a model. I want to display only three records per row. The number of rows is dynamically identified by the number of records in the list. I am getting below error.

```
Only one @model statement is allowed.  Line:16 Col:44

The "td" element was not closed.  All elements must be either self-closing 
or have a matching end tag.  Line:16 Col:10

Encountered end tag "table" with no matching start tag.  Are your start/end tags 
properly balanced?  Line:20 Col:3

The "table" element was not closed.  All elements must be either self-closing or have 
a matching end tag.  Line:8 Col:3

The using block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" 
character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" 
characters are being interpreted as markup.  Line:4 Col:1
```

My CSHTML page looks like below:

```
@model List<Model>
@using (Html.BeginPanel(true))
{
 <table>
 <tr>
   @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
   {
       if (i > 0 && i % 3 == 0)
       {
           @:</tr><tr>
       }
      <td><div id="dataListItem" >@Model[i].bkgNo</div></td>
   }

</tr>
</table> 
}
```

**EDIT 3:** Updated the code as per Stephane's comment. Getting the error marked as bold.

Comment: Why don't you use the same condition logic for both the `<tr>` and `</tr>`?

Comment: "*The using block is missing a closing "}" character.*" - it's not that hard to count how many `{` you have and how many `}`- although your *provided* code ha more `}` than `{` - so I'm guessing it's not the same code that is generating the error.

Comment: My Bad. I have editted the code. And removed the extra }. It still gives the same error @freedomn-m

Comment: Re your edit - you clearly did not do it correctly if your getting each record on a new row. Suggest you show what you have tried so it can be corrected

Comment: It needs to be `<tr>@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++){if (i > 0 && i % 3 == 0){@:</tr><tr>}<td><div id="dataListItem" >@Model[i].bkgNo</div></td>}</tr>` (note that using `@Html.Label()` makes no sense - its not associated with a form control)

Comment: So you've edited to remove the `<tr>`s but not updated the error messages.  So what actually is the problem now?

Comment: @StephenMuecke updated my code. This is what I tried and executed. Each record is printed in a new line.

Comment: Why are you now using bootstrap instead of the `<table>` elements (and do you even have bootstrap.css loaded? (see my previous comment for how do it)

Comment: @StephenMuecke please check now

Comment: No, You check [this working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ArUUY0)

Comment: "*"Only one @model statement is allowed.*" - well that clearly isn't the *only* cshtml code you have - try with a completely blank page and check your _layout.  Maybe add `@{ Layout = null }` at the top.